Different parametrizations of the exponential family
I found in this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450 , formula 10, a parametrization of the exponential family that I think can be written like this:
$$P(t|\eta,s)=e^{\eta t/s}e^{-g(\eta)/s}e^{c(t,s)}$$
I just performed a simple renaming to be (a bit) more compatible with the form I found on Bishop (Pattern Recognition book), formula 4.118 in my version:
$$P(t|\eta,s)=e^{\eta t/s}\frac{1}{s}h\left(\frac{t}{s}\right)g(\eta)$$
Now I understand that one can have different parametrizations of the same thing, e.g. I could try to see if given e $g(*), c(*,*)$, $\eta$ ,$s$ in the first parametrization, I can recover the second form for some choice of new $g(*), h(*)$, $\eta$, $s$ in the second expression, and viceversa. The resulting expression must be valid for any $t$ so that we can confirm that we are able to parametrize the same distributions under the two approaches.
I started doing this exercise and, if requested, I can show where I got, but before continuing I wanted to ask:
Question 1: Is the first parametrization, the one provided in the article, well known? Are there references? I always found the second form of Bishop.
Question 2: Should I see trivially what are the consequences of the two different parametrizations and in what contexts we should use one or the other?


First, just in case, please notice that its an exponential family, not the exponential family. There are many exponential families, but they share many common properties.

There's something fishy going on in the Bishop book. He considers (equation 4.84 and the paragraph before) exponential families with a scale parameter. A family of distributions has a scale parameter iff: $X$ in the family implies $s X$ in the family for all $s > 0$. I'm not quite sure how general that really is and I'm a bit worried that the only such example is the gaussian family.

In contrast, the Ba et al formula is, I think, the general case you get from scaling the family by multiplying the log-likelihood by $1/s$. That's an interesting modification since this is related to obtaining multiple datapoints from the same family.


It is thus normal that the formulas don't match: the $s$ parameters are playing quite different roles in both formulas.
Here is a very-detailed high-quality reference on the topic: https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~blei/fogm/2022F/readings/Efron2018.pdf equations 1.2 and 2.2 are similar to Ba et al's formulation, but they are specific to the repeated sampling case. Note that the s (or $\phi$) parameter is non-standard and doesn't appear in Efron.

Thanks a lot it looks a great reference. I put (+1). A quick reaction to your points. [1] So now I understand that each choice of h and g determine a different exponential family, whose parameters are the eta_s

[2] The exponential distribution has also that property no? it replaces lambda by lambda/s . Isn't it a closure property that one would like to have? E.g. if we fit something we would want to be able to fit both X and sX.... It is true that formula 1.1 in your notes does not seem closed in this respect in the general case. Maybe that is the reason why Bishop adds it by hand? It may be that one recovers this closure property if by "family" we consider g_0 variable as well (in contrast to previous point)... but at the moment I am  a bit confused...

[3] the equation of the notes 1.1 ((1.2) is the i.i.d case of 1.1) seems to me similar to Bishop formulation with s=1. The notes do not even introduce s or phi. Maybe you can comment more on how Ba derived its formulation?

@Thomas 2. Yeah, exponential family is both a scale family and an exponential family, but it's not quite of the form that bishop wants. But he has both the standard exponential family natural parameter and a scale parameter on top? That feels very weird but I'm not brave enough to sit down and do the math. I'm still very suspicious, and I'm not sure if that construction actually gives him anything.

Thanks Guillaume. If you are asking how the Bishop version is derived that I think I can give you my understanding. If f_X(x) is the distribution of X, than Y = sX has distribution f_Y(x)=1/sf(x/s). Take the exponential family as f(x|eta), e.g. formula 1.1 in the notes. Now apply this transformation and get as a new extended family f(x|eta, s) = 1/s f(x/s|eta). This is essentially the formula of Bishop that I wrote. I do not know if this helps... if the initial family was already closed by sX multiplication, e.g. for the Gaussian family, there will be an overparametrization...

For the form of Ba et al. I have your insight at the moment, but I am still puzzled E.g. if you try to apply normalization to the Bishop form you get a nice relation between h and g, one is essentially the Laplace transform of the other, but for the Ba form you get weird conditions... My only explanation at the moment is that everything is build so that their eq. 11 is valid... but since there are no explanations in the article I hoped to find a standard reference where this form is discussed... I should read better the notes of Efron but in the formulas you cited I do not see an s/phi paramet


1.1 and 2.1 are the standard equations for an exponential family. It matches both bishop and Ba with $s=1$. That $s$ parameter is non-standard and doesn't appear in Efron

